# Twitter bootstrap 2 top navigation dropdown with from not working in mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have searched a lot about the problem before posting here, Not found any solution.

Link to the website: http://bit.ly/1geHJr0

I'm using Twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 and included a form in the dropdown menu. Everything  working fine on desktop browsers. On Mobile browser when i click login link in the nav opens login form but it's closing when i click on any field or button in the from, User not able to enter any information as it is closing.

Here is my part of code for the navigation menu

```
<li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin"> <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" href="login" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin"><i class="icon-lock"></i> Login</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu span3" style="background:#0C0;">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'login';?>" id="login">
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email" value="" placeholder="Email" class="span3" />  <?php echo form_error('login_email')?>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password" value="" placeholder="password" class="span3"/>  <?php echo form_error('login_password')?>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="text-left" style="padding-left:8px;">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="login" value="Login" style="background-color: #3498DB;" />
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'forgot_password';?>">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

I tried below code but no luck

```
<script>
    $('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: which browser & whats the version ??? is working for me in firefox

Comment: @AamirShahzad Chrome on Mobile. It's working fine in firefox and chrome on desktop. Mobile Chrome Version is 32.0.1700.99

Comment: can u try using event.stopImmediatePropagation http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/ ? or event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: I just tried it on Mobile Chrome V 32.0.1700.99 on Samsung Galaxy S4 and it worked. Perhaps it could be isolated to a particular range of mobile devices? I feel your pain on this one :( I once had a similar problem: user taps on field and form shows and closes again. It was because an element was hovering over the field. Maybe it could be something similar in your case with screen size?

Comment: @Ravimallya yes tried that too, no that didn't help ;(

Comment: @kleinkie Yes it's not working on some devices and desktop versions of chrome. It's wired problem, many of the bootstrap users are facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem and fixed this issue.

Issue was i have used div instead of ul for the drop down. It's closing when you click other than ul.

I just replaced this

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu span3" style="background:#0C0;">
```

With ul > li

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu span3" style="background:#0C0;">
   <li>
    <form....
   </li>
</ul>
```